# Splitting data into chunks but with distance in between

Tags: r, dataframe, split, partition, seq

Suppose I have the following sequence:

AAAAAAAAAAAAGCC**A**GGTGCGGTGGCTCATGCCTGTAAGCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCAAGGCAGGCGGATCACTAGAGGTCAG

starting from position A (which is bold in the sequence) I want to split it into chunks with a length of 5 characters but I want the chunks to be 3 characters distant from each other meaning I want to get

'GGTGC' , 'GGCTC' , 'CCTGT',  'CCCAG', and so on till the end. Then I would like to get the same information from the bold A to the start of the sequence meaning:

AAGCC, AAAAA ,...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround to do the split i.e. we split at 3 characters (`.` - represents any character in regex) that succeeds 5 characters

```
strsplit(str1, "(?<=.....)...", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
```

Or if we want to construct the pattern dynamically use `strrep` with `paste`

```
n1 <- 200
n2 <- 50
pat <- paste0("(?<=", strrep(".", n1), ")", strrep(".", n2))
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "AAAAAAAAAAAAGCCAGGTGCGGTGGCTCATGCCTGTAAGCCCAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCAAGGCAGGCGGATCACTAGAGGTCAG"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. In the actual problem I want to split it into windows of length 200 with 50 characters in between. How can I avoid using the dots in that case?

Comment: @A4747 you can use `paste0("(?<=", strrep(".", 200), ")", strrep(".", 50))`